# unable to unmarshalling the xml file

Tags: rest, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

In my project, I have generated xml file by `JaxB` object. Now again I want unmarshall as `JAXB` object now. When I am trying to unmarshalling it throws classcastException.

Please find the class I have written:

```
public class ReservationTest1 {

    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException, JAXBException
    {

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(com.hyatt.Jaxb.makeReservation.request.OTAHotelResRQ.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        JAXBElement bookingElement = (JAXBElement) unmarshaller.unmarshal(
                 new FileInputStream("D://myproject//Reservation.xml"));


        System.out.println(bookingElement.getValue());

    }
}
```

Could you please provide me useful information to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

**Why You're Getting a ClassCastException**

If the object being unmarshalled is annotated with `@XmlRootElement` then you will get an instance of that class instead of an instance of `JAXBElement`.

```
FileInputStream xml = new FileInputStream("D://myproject//Reservation.xml");
OTAHotelResRQ booking = (OTAHotelResRQ) unmarshaller.unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
```

**Always Get Domain Object**

If you always want to receive an instance of your domain object regardless of whether a domain object or `JAXBElement` is returned from the unmarshal operation you can use the `JAXBIntrospector`.

```
FileInputStream xml = new FileInputStream("D://myproject//Reservation.xml");
Object result = unmarshaller.unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
OTAHotelResRQ booking = (OTAHotelResRQ) JAXBIntrospector.getValue(result);
```

**Always Get JAXBElement**

If you would rather always receive an instance of `JAXBElement` you can use one of the `unmarshal` methods that takes a class parameter.

```
StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("D://myproject//Reservation.xml");
JAXBElement<OTAHotelResRQ> bookingElement = 
    unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, OTAHotelResRQ.class);
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html